# left join a variable by id in R

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have two tables df1 and df2. Now I want to left join a variable `newVar` of df2 to df1 by the same id. But the problem is that there are some ids exist in df1 but not in df2.

So I want that `if df1.id exists in df2, then df1.newVar=df2.newVar, else df1.newVar=0`.

In R, I've tried `df1$newVar= ifelse((df1$id %in% df2$id), df2$newVar, 0)` but the result was not good.

I've tried also `sqldf('select df1.*, df2.newVar as newVar from df1 left outer join df2 on df2.id= df1.id')` but R gives an error.

Here is an example of df1:

```
id   var1
A     1
A     2
B     1
```

df2:

```
id   newVar
A     1
A     1
```

I want the result of df1 looks like:

```
id   var1   newVar
A     1       1
A     2       1
B     1       0
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your data

Comment: @VidaWang Ok, already updated.

Comment: (1) I don't get any errors when I run your sqldf statement with the data  you posted.  If you really did get an error maybe you made a typo or something else that you did not show.  (2) I do get one warning but you can ignore it. or use an older version of RSQLite. (It was introduced by recent versions of that package.) or just run it twice.  I believe it only gives a warning the first time you use sqldf in a session. (3) you need to use `distinct` if you want the output shown: `sqldf("select distinct * from df1 left join df2 using(id)")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **left_join{dplyr}** to do that work.

```
library("dplyr")
df1 <- data_frame(
  id = c("A", "A", "B"),
  var1 = c(1, 2, 1)
)

df2 <- data_frame(
  id = c("A", "A"),
  newvar = c(1, 1)
)

unique(left_join(df1,df2,by="id"))
```

And the result is :

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
     id  var1 newvar
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     A     1      1
2     A     2      1
3     B     1     NA
```

Comment: If df2 have many variables and I only want the `newVar`, how should I do?

Comment: @ velvetrock you can first filter the variables in df2, and then do left-join, like `unique(left_join(df1, select(df2, id, newvar),by="id"))`